On Task "Related to Id" is not getting updated to "NULL": Working in Debug mode but not in Real Time
I am creating a Record Trigger After Save flow on Task, "when a record is created" with the Task Subtype ="List Email" and then Updating the Related to Id = Null, after updating this, Getting related lead(WhoId) from the task to check for the conditions and updating the Lead Status and First_Email_Sent__c. This all is working good in debug mode but not in real time.
Below is my flow




DEBUG DETAILS

Expected Result

Final Result
I want to make Related to Id "NULL" but not working in flow as expected. The flow is not updating the id to NULL.


Please [edit] your post to describe specifically what is not working and what specific results you get compared to what you expect.
